# Looping through netsh for specific interface and storing IP address to variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to assign the IP address of the interface Loopback to a variable but for some reason I get nothing.
This works if I type it in the command shell:

```
C:\temp>netsh interface ip show config name="Loopback" | find  "IP Address"
IP Address:                           192.168.255.10
```

But when I loop through it output is empty...

```
set _netsh_cmd=netsh interface ip show config name="Loopback"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('%_netsh_cmd% ^| find "IP Address"') DO echo [%%G]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an error, but in the for loop you added a colon to the find string.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried both with and without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error, you have to turn on delayedExpansion, and make the `_netsh_cmd` surrounded with `!` rather than `%`. this should be correct:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set _netsh_cmd=netsh interface ip show config name="Loopback"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('!_netsh_cmd! ^| find "IP Address:"') DO echo [%%G]
```

Comment: Heh, no problem. i typically avoid most errors within blocks of code by always coding with `delayedExpansion` on, and rarely use `%`, even if it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine without delayed exapnsion.

```
@echo off
set _netsh_cmd=netsh interface ip show config "Loopback"
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('%_netsh_cmd% ^|find "IP Address"') DO echo [%%G]
```